# Qt application won't run on a specific machine

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw, compatibility

I have a Qt application compiled with MinGW 32bit.

It works on all our windows machines but one. On this machine, upon launching the application it briefly shows up under 'Processes' in the windows task manager, but then disappears. 
The application window is never shown, nor is any error message.

Any ideas on how to possibly debug this? I have absolutely no information on what is happening; it just doesnt start.

Comment: If you make sure that all dependencies are correctly installed on that system like VC++ redist, Qt libs then you can go for a Dependency walker comparison with the system where the application is launching correctly.

Comment: if your process show in 'processes' tab and then disappear, a logical error occurred,  for example your code is handling machine windows version and make a decision to close if running on windows XP sp 3

Comment: Does this happen with both debug and release configurations?

Answer (score 1):

You'd debug it under a debugger of course. There are two approaches:

1. Install the debugger and the debug symbols for your application on the target machine, and go from there.
2. If you don't want to debug on the target, you can also add a crash reporter to your application. That way you'll get a process dump that you can reconcile with the debug symbols and open both in the debugger on the development machine to see what state the application was in when it had crashed. [crashrpt](http://crashrpt.sourceforge.net)'s documentation and examples should get you started on this approach.